# Google Cloud Platform: Cloud Functions and Cloud Tasks doesn't work with authorized service account email

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I created a service account email and added `cloudfunctions.invoker` role to the email so I can make sure only cloud tasks can trigger cloud functions, and I removed `AllUsers` role. But when cloud tasks tried to run cloud function, the status code is `UNAUTHENTICATED(16): HTTP status code 401` and execution failed.

My current code and console is like this.

`index.ts`

```
export const addTasks = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'You are not authenticated.')
  }

  const client = new tasks.CloudTasksClient()

  const projectId = functions.config().project.id
  const queue = 'queue'
  const location = functions.config().project.location
  const parent = client.queuePath(projectId, location, queue)
  const url = `https://${location}-${projectId}.cloudfunctions.net/executeSomething`
  const serviceAccountEmail = functions.config().project.email

  const task: tasks.protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.ITask = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url: url,
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail: serviceAccountEmail,
      },
    },
    scheduleTime: {
      seconds: ...,
    },
  }

  const request: tasks.protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.ICreateTaskRequest = {
    parent: parent,
    task: task,
  }

  return client.createTask(request)
}
```

My cloud function's console

[image]

I added the cloud functions invoker role to the service account email.

My firebase project environment variables

[image]

When I added `AllUsers` role to cloud functions, it works as expected so I am sure I made a mistake when resrticting access. What am I missing?

Update:

My cloud tasks console

[image]
[image]

Comment: This might be a longshot, but the example that was shared in the answer below has the `serviceAccountEmail` around quotes. Could you try using `"service_account_email": service_account_email` and check if it fixes the issue?

Comment: DId you find out what was not working?

Comment: @Black_Bacardi Not yet..

Answer (score 2):

for me removing `audience: new URL(url).origin,` from `oidcToken` object inside `task` resolved the `UNAUTHENTICATED(16): HTTP status code 401` issue.

```js
const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url,
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail: email,
        //audience: new URL(url).origin, 
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body,
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OIDC token seems broken against [the specification](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2#oidctoken)

Simply provide the email, without the attribute name like in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-tasks#creating_http_tasks_with_authentication_tokens), or use the snake_case like described in the spec

Comment: I tried with `test-653@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and updated my environment variables and deploy functions again but it still faied. (I input `test` and a random number is automatically added) I don't think the problem comes from the name. I attached some pictures. Please take a look.

Comment: 401 means "you haven't provide authentication header", that's why I focused on the correct service account email definition. I would prefer a 403 "you are authenticated, but not authorized, or the token isn't readable/valid". I'm strongly convinced that the call is performed without Authorization header. But I don't know why it continues to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `audience` did the trick for me.
Here is how my task object look like -

```json
    const task = {
      httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        url,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        oidcToken: { 
          serviceAccountEmail: sa, 
          audience: aud 
        },
      },
    };
```

[nodejs doc](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/2.3.1/google.cloud.tasks.v2.IOidcToken.html)